# Unknown issue with recursive integer partition calculator in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm having some trouble with my recursive program to calculate the number of integer partitions of an integer.

Here's what I have written:

```
def p(k, n):
    if k > n:
        return 0
    if k == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return (p(k+1, n) + p(k, n-k))

def partitions(n):
    ans = 1
    for k in range(1, n/2):
        ans += p(k, n-k)
    return ans
```

This algorithm is implemented from Wikipedia's article [Partition (number theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Intermediate_function). Here's what my program outputs for the first few integers:

```
partitions(0) = 1
partitions(1) = 1
partitions(2) = 1
partitions(3) = 1
partitions(4) = 2
partitions(5) = 2
partitions(6) = 2
partitions(7) = 2
```

I'm not sure why my program doesn't operate properly, since I thought I correctly implemented both recursion and the algorithm from Wikipedia. Could somebody help me understand what it's doing?

Answer (score 2):

You have one of the base cases wrong:

```
if k == 1:
    return 1
```

should be

```
if k == n:
    return 1
```

Additionally:

```
for k in range(1, n / 2):
```

should be

```
for k in range(1, n / 2 + 1):
```

This is because the sum in the formula is *inclusive* of the upper bound, but in Python, the `range` does not include the upper bound. Then:

```
print [partitions(i) for i in range(1, 8)]
```

gives

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 15]
```

matching the values given in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Intermediate_function).

Comment: And that's why you shouldn't code when sleep deprived. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems:

This:

```
if k == 1:
```

should be `if k == n:`, and this loop:

```
for k in range(1, n/2):
```

should be `range(1, n/2+1)` -- or better, `range(1, n//2+1)` to be explicit about the fact we want integer division -- because `range` in Python doesn't include the upper bound.  After fixing those, I get:

```
>>> [partitions(i) for i in range(1,10)]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 15, 22, 30]
```

(which, you'll notice, only has 9 values. :^)